# Table too wide in iopart class

Tags: floats, formatting, layout, journal-publishing, journal

I'm preparing my first manuscript for journal submission with the `iopart` document class. Since it's for a publication, there are typesetting constraints imposed on me (that I'm not always aware of). I'd like to include a table in the paper, but it's too wide for the manuscript for the time being. I include the table like

```
\begin{table}
\caption{\label{tab:table} Caption.}
\begin{indented}
\footnotesize
\item[]\begin{tabular}{@{}lllllll}
\br
Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 & Heading 4 & Heading 5 & Heading 6 & Heading 7 \\
\mr
1.1 & 1.2 & 1.3 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.6 & 1.7 \\
2.1 & 2.2 & 2.3 & 2.4 & 2.5 & 2.6 & 2.7 \\
\br
\end{tabular}
\end{indented}
\end{table}
```

One way to slightly narrow the table that I've seen people do is to split longer headings over two lines. How do I do that? Has anyone else written an article for an IOP journal with a wide table and can share what other tricks they used to fit it to the page within the journals's guidelines?

Comment: Just get rid of the `indented` wrapper environment and the `\item` statement.

Comment: @Mico , I *think* that that is part of the formatting specifications for IOP journals. Like I said, this is my first article, so I could be mistaken. Is it your understanding that the indented wrapper isn't necessary for IOP journals, or just that it would save some horizontal space?

Comment: Please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point (ii) on page 20 of the user guide of the iopart document class says the following about tables and the `indented` environment:

> The normal style is for tables to be indented. This is accomplished by using `\begin{indented} . . . \end{indented}` and putting `\item[]` before the start of the tabular environment. *Omit these commands* for any tables which will not fit on the page when indented. [emphasis added]

Since the `indented` wrapper is preventing the tabular material from fitting inside the text block, you actually have official permission to get rid of the `indented` wrapper.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}
\usepackage{showframe} % <-- draw framelines around text block
                       % (omit from real document)

\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\caption{Caption.}\label{tab:table} 
\footnotesize
\centering % <-- new

\begin{tabular}{@{} lllllll @{}}
\br
Heading 1 & Heading 2 & Heading 3 & Heading 4 & 
Heading 5 & Heading 6 & Heading 7 \\
\mr
1.1 & 1.2 & 1.3 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.6 & 1.7 \\
2.1 & 2.2 & 2.3 & 2.4 & 2.5 & 2.6 & 2.7 \\
\br
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you - I missed that sentence during my rereads of the style guide. That sure makes it easier :)